# Create 3D objects from 2D image and export as a 3D model

Tags: export, image-processing, image3d

I want to create 3D  objects from 2D image and export it as a "3ds" file (or "obj").

I tried:

```
img=Import["https://i.imgur.com/orbbFG4.png"]
```

[image]

```
With[{mesh = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[img]]}, RegionProduct[mesh, Line[{{0.}, {55}}]]]
```

[image]

```
Export["RamF.3ds", %]
```

but there is an error message

[image]

I also tried

```
Export["RamF.obj", %]
```

it works, but there is a problem  when I tried to import it into the Blender or Unity3D.

Comment: You need to state the file format in Export:  Try `Export["RamF.3ds, %, "3DS"]`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No. It'll determine that automatically. The primary issue is that ["Export to the 3DS format supports the following graphics primitives: GraphicsComplex, Cuboid, Cylinder, and Sphere."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/3DS.html#1150224632). You'll need to call `Show` on your mesh and then turn the `Prism` objects into `Polygon` ones.

Comment: FYI: the formula contains a typo. `36390` should read `26390` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is the `Prism` primitive that is used to construct the 3D form. I'm using your original code

```
m3 = With[{mesh = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[img]]}, 
    RegionProduct[mesh, Line[{{0.}, {55}}]]
]
```

Now, we can inspect how the 3D text is built:

```
With[{mp = MeshPrimitives[m3, 3]},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[mp[[1 ;; i]], PlotRange -> RegionBounds[m3]],
  {i, 2, Length[mp]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

You see, every little piece is a prism. Basically, Mathematica creates a triangularized version of your text surface and extends it into the z-axis by turning it into a 3D prism.

Converting a `Prism` into a set of `Polygons` is, however, really easy. Simply turn the bottom, the top, and all the sides into a polygon.

```
toPolygons[Prism[{a1_, a2_, a3_, b1_, b2_, b3_}]] := Polygon[
  {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {a1, b1, b2, a2}, 
   {a2, b2, b3, a3}, {a3, b3, b1, a1}}]
```

Using this function, you can export it to a 3D format

```
Export["~/tmp/f.3ds", Graphics3D[toPolygons /@ MeshPrimitives[m3, 3]]]
```

import it into blender and it will work:

[image]