# Summation does not simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, summation

Inspired by the identity listed in [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165067/create-3d-objects-from-2d-image-and-export-as-a-3d-model), I tried

```
2 π Sqrt[2]/9801 Sum[((4 k)! (1103 + 36390 k))/((k!)^4  396^(4 k)), 
  {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

and got

```
(1/(418435621956 Sqrt[2])) π 
(188362204272 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {1, 1}, 1/96059601] + 
6065 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/4, 3/2, 7/4}, {2, 2}, 1/96059601])
```

`FullSimplify` did not lead to any simplification or the desired answer:  $1$.

However, `N[%]` yielded 1.

Why didn't this summation equality get evaluated symbolically to yield the answer $1$?

Comment: In fact, `N[%-1]` doesn't yield zero, it yields $8.8\cdot 10^{-9}$. Are you completely sure the sum is indeed one? Or may it just be close?

Comment: I'm assuming the *equality* identity (not approximation) given in the linked problem is correct, but perhaps this is a mistake.

Comment: I got the one when I run this and I ask for the numerical value. 

However, when I subtract one from the other I get something close to zero, namely $-2.81647*10^{-9}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct formula is with a `26390` instead of `36390`. See (78) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html). Mathematica now outputs the correct result:

```
\[Pi] Sqrt[8]/9801 Sum[((4 k)! (1103 + 26390 k))/((k!)^4 396^(4 k)), {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]
(* 1 *)
```

Hooray!

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!